# Center align of text of title bar in Android

Tags: android

I'm new at Android programming so I don't know all the features.
As I understood, all generated activities has a title bar which contains app_name string resource. I managed to change title of sole activity but I don't understand how to change alignment of the text of the title. I mean, the're generated like this:

[image]

but I need it to be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using support toolbar , the approach will be easy.
just add a text view inside it and make it centered :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >


     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toolbar Title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

in your activity you can access the title like so:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
TextView Title = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
```

Answer (score 2):

To have a centered title in ABS (if you want to have this in the default ActionBar, just remove the "support" in the method names), you could just do this:

In your Activity, in your `onCreate()` method:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout);
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="my Title"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now you should have an Actionbar with just a title. If you want to set a custom background, set it in the Layout above (but then don't forget to set android:layout_height="match_parent").

Comment: If i put a button inside this layout, how can i set the click listener on it?